# Dynamically populated fields from JSON in Android

Tags: java, android, json

Greetings fellow programmers!

I am building a mobile app where I fetch JSON data from an API then transfer it using bundle to next activity (all of that works perfectly). In the second activity the **JSON** data transferred (in the form of a string) is supposed to be used to dynamically populate fields.

Now what I am trying to do is that I am trying to extract names of the companies from my **JSON** data, populate them into buttons dynamically and use the rest of **JSON** data (such as phone numbers, emails etc) to display information only when the button (with the name of the company on it) is clicked on. 
Ideally I would want to use an accordion button but after doing some research apparently it cannot be easily implemented in Android. So I was thinking of using a dialog box (with the rest of the info) that would pop up after pressing a button with the company name on it.

I am not sure where to begin to be honest with dynamical population of buttons and then dialog boxes from **JSON** data, so I would hoping that maybe someone from this amazing community could give me some pointers?

I would be extremely grateful for any help!!

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to convert complete JSON into your desired class?

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to parse JSON - convert it to java object.
You could either use GSON library, or do it yourself using JSONObject class.

Its quite simple, and if you are using Retrofit library for networking, there's a good chance that it does it for you.

Once you got your java models - objects created based on your JSON, just assign the values to controls. By the way, if you are using list of buttons, it is a good idea to use RecyclerView to create list.

You can find details here:

[GSON library](http://guides.codepath.com/android/leveraging-the-gson-library)
[Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Answer (score 0):

Create an class for Company with members like name,address,phone-number,email etc ..... 
Create list of objects of Company class from json data ..

```
Eg : 
List<Company> companies  =  new ArrayList<>();
jsonArray = new JsonArray(jsonInstring);
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
jsonObject = jsonArray.getJsonObject(i);
company = new Company(jsonObject.getString("name"),......);
companies.add(company);
}
```

Now populate those data to list view or recyclerview and on click of item pass that object company and create a dialog... and inside that dialogView set value from that object to views.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Comapny Bean with id, name, number and other fields
2. Parse your json and create list of Company Bean as `List<Company> companyList`
3. In activity_main.xml file create a containerLayout for adding dynamic views

   `<LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/containerLayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"/>`
4. Create button_layout.xml

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/button"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />`

5.In your activity call addButton method

```
private void addButton(){
        containerLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.containerLayout);
        for(int i=0; i<companyList.size(); i++){
            containerLayout.addView(generateButton(companyList.get(i)));
        }
    }

    private Button generateButton(Company company) {
        Button companyButton = (Button)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.button_layout, null);
        companyButton.setText(company.getName());
        companyButton.setTag(company);
        companyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPopup((Company)v.getTag()); //other details popup
            }
        });
        return companyButton;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert JSON response to your Java class object, then In that case JAKSON API will be perfect for your task.

you can convert JSON to any java object in this way.

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   //Object to JSON in file
    User user = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), User.class);
```

Please follow referral [URL](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) for more information.

Hope this will help you.